# Why am I getting an error for my symbolic link program?

Tags: c, symlink, unistd.h

So I'm trying to compile this code [symbolic_link.c] that will let me create a symbolic link for a protected file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int symlink(const char *, const char *);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    unlink(argv[1]);
    symlink("./passwd",argv[1]);
}
```

When I compile, the error I get is:

```
symbolic_link.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `symlink'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code compiles properly on Linux but not on Windows 10 minGW.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Where in your opinion is the definition of symlink to be found?

Comment: Windows 10 does not have `symlink`, therefore MinGW does not provide it.